# Report that displays only accounts that have open opportunities which have different opportunity owners

Tags: formula, reporting, opportunity, account

I am trying to clean up accounts on our org. We want to achieve the goal of that all accounts will have only one opportunity owner. To do this we need to clean up accounts that have more than one open opportunity AND have different opportunity owners. I am hoping to achieve this via a report and trying to avoid using flows. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with standard report filters.  The easiest solution is probably to export all your open opps to a CSV and use Excel to set a single owner for each account's open opps.